# Are there any example apps or tutorials on how to do Push Notifications in Ionic 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I've been trying for a while now to get push notifications working in Ionic 2.

But I'm not getting further.

I was wondering if any of you might've come across something that might help.

Comment: Have a look to documentation of [push](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/Push/)

Comment: I wrote an answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/37634072/4017375, it might help

Comment: because ionic 2 was still in beta you could hardly get an up to date walk through as the framework keeps changing