# Ionic 2 Push notification error

Tags: android, ionic2

I used below this code

```
import {Push} from 'ionic-native';

initializeApp() {

this.platform.ready().then(() => {

  StatusBar.styleDefault();

  var push = Push.init({

    android: {

      senderID: "484777065207"

    },

    ios: {

      alert: "true",

      badge: true,

      sound: 'false'

    },

    windows: {}

  });

  push.on('registration', (data) => {

    console.log(data.registrationId);

    alert(data.registrationId.toString());

  });

  push.on('notification', (data) => {

    console.log(data);

    alert("Hi, Am a push notification");

  });

  push.on('error', (e) => {

    console.log(e.message);

  });

});
```

}

[Result Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XqE7.jpg)
But when I tried this code I got out put in mobile , but I got only the alert display but I didn't get notifications display.. 
I have attached my mobile screen out put..

So can you plzz send me ionic 2 push notifications code...

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article to explain push notifications for both iOS and Android. See if that's useful [Ionic 2 Push Notifications](https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59)

Right now, I couldn't find any documentation on Ionic 2 website for Push notification. But using this link [Ionic 2 Push](http://nishanthkabra.com/ionic2push.html) and [Phonegap plugin push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#parameters), I am able to get basic notifications at least on android.

I have following code in my MainApp constructor

```
 constructor(platform:Platform, private app:IonicApp) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        });

        var push = Push.init({
            android: {
                senderID: "YOUR_SENDER_ID"
            },
            ios: {
                alert: "true",
                badge: true,
                sound: 'false'
            },
            windows: {}
        });

        push.on('registration', (data) => {
            console.log("registraiton id " + data.registrationId);
        });

        push.on('notification', (data) => {
            console.log(data.message);
            console.log(data.title);
            console.log(data.count);
            console.log(data.sound);
            console.log(data.image);
            console.log(data.additionalData);
        });

        push.on('error', (e) => {
            console.log(e.message);
        });

}
```

And on server side, I am using following code for push notification

```
var express = require('express');
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var app = express();
var gcmApiKey = 'YOUR_GCM_API_KEY'; // GCM API KEY OF YOUR GOOGLE CONSOLE PROJECT

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('server is just fine!');
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send("This is basic route");
});

app.get('/push', function (req, res) {
    var device_tokens = []; //create array for storing device tokens

    var retry_times = 4; //the number of times to retry sending the message if it fails
    var sender = new gcm.Sender(gcmApiKey); //create a new sender
    var message = new gcm.Message(); //create a new message
    message.addData('title', 'PushTitle');
    message.addData('message', "Push message");
    message.addData('sound', 'default');
    message.collapseKey = 'Testing Push'; //grouping messages
    message.delayWhileIdle = true; //delay sending while receiving device is offline
    message.timeToLive = 3; //number of seconds to keep the message on
    //server if the device is offline

    //Take the registration id(lengthy string) that you logged
    //in your ionic v2 app and update device_tokens[0] with it for testing.
    //Later save device tokens to db and
    //get back all tokens and push to multiple devices
    device_tokens[0] = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    sender.send(message, device_tokens[0], retry_times, function (result) {
        console.log('push sent to: ' + device_tokens);
        res.status(200).send('Pushed notification ' + device_tokens);
    }, function (err) {
        res.status(500).send('failed to push notification ');
    });
});
```

I started a thread [Ionic 2 Push Thread](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-push-notification/53898) on Ionic website for Push notification document, if you want, you can follow that thread.

Steps to run the server. On OS X, you might need to run following commands with `sudo`.

- Download Nodejs from [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/). It will install node and npm in your system.
- `npm install express-generator -g`
- `express MySampleApp`
- `cd MySampleApp`
- `npm install --save node-gcm`
- `npm install`
- Change contents of app.js with above server code and then run server using following command
- `node app.js`

Comment: i Have one more doubt in this code, you mentioned sever side code but i don't know where to use that sever side code. plzz tell me where to use that code

Comment: @Ankush you have not used `ionic io init` command does that mean our app gets notified without that command ( i really not able to follow your answer)

Comment: @MohanGopi Please follow https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59 It has fully working client and server code on github along with detailed instructions